# Java replaceAll Regex for special character [

Tags: java, regex

I am having regex expression problem. need helps from regex experts!
It's fairly simple but I can't get it to work.

I know if I want to check the starting of a text, I should use ^
and ending of the text, I should use $

I want to replace `[quote]` to `<a>quote</a>`.

This doesn't seems to work..

```
String test = "this is a [quote]"
test.replaceAll("^\\[", "<a>");
test.replaceAll("\\]$", "</a>");
```

I want the string to become `"this is a <a>quote</a>"`..

Comment: Regex will only work for this if you can guarantee that there are no nested quotes.  For nested quotes, you'll need something more powerful (a stack).  Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace `[` and `]` with pair, you need to replace them in one time.

```
String test = "this [test] is a [quote]";
String result = test.replaceAll("\\[([^\\]]+)\\]", "<a>$1</a>");
```

Answer (score 2):

`^` implies that you are looking for something at the beginning of the string. However `[` does not appear at the beginning of the string, so you will not have a match. Just do:

```
test.replaceAll("\\[", "<a>");
test.replaceAll("\\]", "</a>");
```

Also, you cannot modify a String in-place. you'll have to assign the output to something. You can do:

```
test = test.replaceAll("\\[", "<a>").replaceAll("\\]", "</a>");
```

That is if you still want to use the variable `test`.